# Hash Functions and storage in hash table

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable, hash-function

I am studying programming and in the school book it states that given key x, hashtable A[] and hash function h() the key x it is stored in A[h(x)-1] position (with C++ implementation). 
However, using as hash function the function h(x)=xmodM, where M is the length of the hashtable, I don't get where keys with mod 0 are stored.
For instance, if M=10 and x=60, where I should store the key value?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the book you're reading mentioning a hash functions like `h(x) = x mod M`? The book probably assumes that the hash function returns a value in the range 1 to M (inclusive).

Comment: Actually, it does! That's why I am confused.

Comment: Maybe time to find some other book? :)

Comment: Haha, well yes, maybe it's time :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how `h()` is defined, if it accepts values starting with 1, then this is why you have `-1` in this formula: `h(x)-1`. Arrays in c++ are indexed starting from 0.

If you compute reminder of dividing of 60 by 10 in c++, then you will get value `0` (`60 % 10 = 0`). In such case it makes no sense to subtract -1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I couldn't agree more. 
The thing is that the book is getting a bit confusing when it comes to that specific example and that's why I asked